# visibility property effects fade effects. Is there an other way to make items invisible without breaking fade effects?

Tags: visibility, fadein, hidden, fadeout, jscript

FadeIn and FadeOut effects works fine alone (without any visibility property). However item should be hidden at first then it should fade in and out. So i made the visibility of the object hidden but it crushed fade effects. Object stays hidden all the time.

If i don't make it hidden at first, fade effects works but the item should be hidden when page is loaded.

Is there a way to make the object invisible at first without effecting fading effects?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use of one the following alternatives:

- `position:absolute; left: -9999px;`
- `position:absolute; clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);`
- `position:absolute; z-index:-1;`